# Is there a hidden meaning in the Alaska sex scene?

Tags: the-simpsons

There seems to be a striking similarity in the ambiance in the Alaska sex scene and the one in Disney's Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs. Was this intentional?

[image: Snow white]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the animals appear to be from Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs whereas the action of the animals interacting with clothing comes from Sleeping Beauty. Some animated shows give reference to Disney movies, for example in Shrek with Fiona singing.

It was very much intentional mostly likely as light-hearted humor. The scene is to point out the inspiration to Disney while at the same time at the last moment to give an exception to the norm (Homer and Marge Simpson in bed while the animals watch in horror).

Comment: So it **is** just for the lulz, eh?

Comment: It's a parody that has been used for years in various animations in the comedy genre.